# How to overwrite body property in component?

Tags: angular

I have default `style.sass` file with common styles of SAP.

It file contains styles of `body {}`.

How to overwrite this CSS property from any component? For example I need to change background color of body in component Login.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do that you need to set `ViewEncapsulation.None`:

```
import {..., ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
```

All styles inside this component will be added to the global styles.

Here is the quote from the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation):

> None means that Angular does no view encapsulation. Angular adds the
>   CSS to the global styles. The scoping rules, isolations, and
>   protections discussed earlier don't apply. This is essentially the
>   same as pasting the component's styles into the HTML.

Comment: Does it mean that styles in main file will be not apply to component?

Comment: it means that they will be applied to the entire page. If you have `h1 {color:green}` selector, text in *all h1 elements*  on the page will be green, not only inside the template of this component

Comment: So, this option isolates local CSS  from global? And apply only local?

Comment: yes, if you use default/native the styles will be isolted, if `none` - the styles will not be isoluted

Comment: Import from Core?

Comment: yeah, `import {..., ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';`

Comment: @Vega, I dont think its possible

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, in your css component :

```
/deep/ body {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: In angular4.3 /deep/ can be replaced by ::ng-deep I think

Comment: body and not .body :)

Comment: deep is relevant for children, not parents

Comment: If you use ::ng-deep the style is not removed when you switch pages with ng-route. Only when you refresh